# String commands in the file path

Tags: string, filepath

I wanted to write the file path into a variable so i used the str to do that and got that:

[\f inside of the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF5b8.png)

and that happens often so how do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace all your `\` with `\\`.**

*From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):*

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.